# Calculating bindPose matrix (Skeletal Animation)

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, matrix, skeletal-mesh

Ive succesfully parsed the iqe (Inter Quake Exporter) format and now im stuck at displaying it in bindpose.

All vertices have a weird transformation, where root bone(which covers the full mesh for orientation) is not the only bone with influence for that vertex. You can see it at the arm / should / neck area of the mesh. This mesh has 3 bones. One root bone overing the whole mesh and two arm bones.
You can see how the mesh should look like in the background (exported as obj)
[image]

For better understanding, i have the following system:

**1.** I load all vertex data into one big vbo 
(vertices, uvs, normals, tangent, bitangent, boneIndicies(4) (index of joint list) and boneWeights(4))

**2.** I add all joints to a joint list and create a tree system (simple linked list with position, rotation and parent pointer)

**3.** i have a seperate list called boneMatrices where i store.. well my bone matrices. currently every frame, later i will precalculate the matrices for each animation frame.

I try to calculate the bone matrix the following way:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this->jointList.size(); i++)
    {
        pixel::CJoint *joint = this->jointList.at(i);


        std::cout << "Joint ------- " << joint->name << " -------- values: \n";
        std::cout << "Translation: " << joint->position.x << " " << joint->position.y << " " << joint->position.z << "\n";
        std::cout << "Quaternion: " << joint->rotation.x << " " << joint->rotation.y << " " << joint->rotation.z << " " << joint->rotation.w << "\n";


        pixel::matrix4 rotation = pixel::CMatrix::fromQuaternion(joint->rotation);
        pixel::matrix4 offset = pixel::CMatrix::translateMatrix(joint->position);
        pixel::matrix4 baseMatrix = rotation * offset; // translation * rotation


        joint->bindPose = baseMatrix;
        joint->invBindPose = pixel::CMatrix::inverseMatrix(baseMatrix);

        if (joint->parent != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Joint: " << joint->name << " is child of " << joint->parent->name << " \n";
            joint->bindPose = joint->bindPose * joint->parent->invBindPose;
            joint->invBindPose = pixel::CMatrix::inverseMatrix(joint->bindPose);
        }


        std::cout << "\n";
    }
```

I store the transposed (else the mesh is upside down) of joint->invBindPose in the boneMatrices and send it to the shader:

boneMatrix is a std::vector of matrix4

```
this->material.setParameter("boneMatrix", this->boneMatrices.at(0), this->boneMatrices.size());
```

The root bone bind calculation has to be right (at least i think) because the head is at the right place and the eyes too (which dont have a bone influence currently)

Comment: Looking at the screenshot: Do you collapse the mesh (multiply all vectors by inverse of baseframe bones) before applying animations to it?

Comment: Sorry for the late replying. No i dont do this. Is this needed?

Comment: I think yes, try it. Also the way you accumulate parent matrices looks suspicious, but I'm no C++ expert to say for sure.